# grep multiple date stamped logs for a particular error message then determine which date stamped log has greatest error message count

Tags: grep, scripting

Hi looking for a solution as per title.

I know how to count a particular error message in one date stamped log but struggling to figure out how to do this across multiple logs and then show which log has the greatest error message incidence.

for a single date stamped log file e.g.

```
log1 = message.log.2022-01-07
log2 = message.log.2022-01-06
log3 = message.log.2022-01-05
log4 = message.log.2022-01-04

error message = ErrorCode123
```

to count incidence of error message in log 1:

```
grep ErrorCode123 message.log.2022-01-07 | wc -l
```

but how can I automate this across each of the four logs in order to show which log has the greatest count. Ideally looking to use some sort of wildcard too in order to accommodate any given number of logs (not just four) that follow the same naming convention e.g. `message.log.*`

If trying to use `grep` in this way is unrealistic then any other method would be great too.

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/685489/edit) your question and use the provided formatting options (especially the code formatting `{}`).

Answer (score 2):

Number of matches in reverse order :

```
grep -c ErrorCode123 message.log.* | awk -F':' '{print $2, $1}' | sort -nr
7 message.log.2022.01-05
4 message.log.2022.01-07
3 message.log.2022.01-06
```

Return highest match only : add `| head -1`

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a file with 4 matches and the other with less:

```
$ grep -n ErrorCode123 message.log.* | sort -rt: -k2,2 | sort -ut: -k1,1 | sort -rt: -k2,2 | head -1
message.log.2022-01-04:4:ErrorCode123
```

Now the problem that could arise is that you have more than 1 file with the same number of matches.

Comment: Thank you this is also really useful.